# C# Web API sharing log class between classes - ThreadStatic Singleton

Tags: c#, variables, asp.net-web-api

I am building a web API in C#.  In the web API I have multiple functions.  I also have other classes in the same project used to split code.
In the API I want a class that I can add data to as the code is running regardless of what code is running.

Use case:
At the beginning of the call I want to set up a log class that will be able store information for me to insert in a db in a finally block.  Anywhere in the code I want the ability to add pieces of information in to this class.  At the beginning I would add information about variables. In the middle I would add what the program did and if an error happened specific information about the error.  At the end I would set the execution time.
I believe that if I declare this lg class static then information could change if more then one api is being processed at the same time.

I guess my question is this: how would I create a "global" class that is thread safe for use in a web API?

Edit: I need to store this class in my DB.  To use log4net I would need to write a custom log function with custom SQL to insert stuff to my DB

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Endpoint { get; set; }
public string Response { get; set; }
public DateTime RequestTime { get; set; }
public DateTime ResponseTime { get; set; }
public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
public string Controller { get; set; }
public string Version { get; set; }
public string ApplicationDescription { get; set; }
public string ApplicationVersion { get; set; }
public string Param1 { get; set; }
public string Param2 { get; set; }
public string Param3 { get; set; }
public string Param4 { get; set; }
public string Param5 { get; set; }
public string Param6 { get; set; }
public string Param7 { get; set; }
public string Param8 { get; set; }
public string Param9 { get; set; }
public string ParamBlob { get; set; }
public string IPAddress { get; set; }
```

Edit(Solution): After Batavia answer I found that a singleton was the way to go.  after testing I saw that this was not thread independent. so when I made 2 threads both edited the same data and the data was getting mixed between the 2 threads.  the way I solved this was this:

```
public sealed class Logger
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Logger instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();
    public int test;
    Logger()
    {
    }

    public static Logger Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new Logger();
                    }

                }

            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

The following test program is used to test:

```
    var t = new Thread(_ =>
    {
        var x = Logger.Instance;
        x.test = 2;
        Console.WriteLine("t " + x.test);
        Thread.Sleep(30);
        Console.WriteLine("t after " + x.test);
    });
    var t1 = new Thread(_ =>
    {
        var y = Logger.Instance;
        y.test = 3;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        Console.WriteLine("t1 " + y.test);
    });
    t.Start();
    t1.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The whole point of a singleton (as i wrote it) is that you had 1 global instance of your class. In case of your test program you could also just have used a local variable and then the count of tests in both threads would have been different.

Comment: This is a test program to test thread saftey.  It is not a use case.

Comment: I've seen test safety often referred to as multiple threads accessing the same resource (for example writing 2 log lines in such a way an other thread doesn't write anything between those 2).
This is more thread separation.

So what is the thread safety issue you are trying to solve? for just inserting a class in your db you don't need thread safety

Comment: Passing a class that is used for logging as a variable between classes/functions will get confusing and cluncky.  The problem with a static variable(as with a conventional singleton) is if 2 api requests come in at the same time, the first one will set the endpoint to "endpoint1" and the second will set it to "endpoint2" when it gets written to the database both calls will have a value of "endpoint2" even though this is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) to do your logging. I have used it with great success. It's robust and can log to files or databases. See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html for configuration examples.

**Update** I think the easiest way is to create an instance of that class in the beginning of the call and then pass it around to the various other classes. At the end of the call, you can then store it into your database. This way it will be protected from the other API calls. No need for a global class.

Comment: Completely agree. There's no point re-inventing the wheel when there's a tried and tested method to do everything you want and more.

Comment: I use log4net for writing log files to a disc.  I will edit my post to show what I need stored in the DB.

Answer (score -3):

for a global threadsafe class you should think of the singleton design pattern

```
public class Logger {
     private static object _lock = new object();
     private static Logger _logger = null;

     public static Instance { get {
          if ( _logger == null ) {
             lock(_lock) {
                 if ( _logger == null ) {
                     _logger = new Logger();
                 }
             }
          }
     }
     private Logger() {}

     public void LogMessage(string message) {
          //code to log here, 
     }
}
```

also for logging check out log4net which is a feature reach logger including log to db.

Comment: it is if you use the lock inside the logmessage (original question wasn't clear about how/what to log)